# What hardware do I need to turn a few LEDs on/off from HTML?

Tags: microcontroller

This is a beginner question. I tried to search the internet for a solution, but I did not find any that meets all my requirements.

I am writing an HTML file that I would like to distribute to some users to use locally on their computer/phone (I chose html/javascript, because I wanted a platform independent solution.)

Part of the goal is to turn 16 LEDs on/off independently, based on user interaction with the HTML file.

I suppose I need a microcontroller and a way to communicate with it. My problem is that all solutions I found involves installing or setting up something (or I simply did not understand the resources I found.) I would be OK with this, but I would like to pass on the result to users, so a plug-and-play solution would be what I need.

Here is what I need:

- Hardware to control 16 LEDs (microcontroller?)
- Communication with the hardware from plain HTML without any setup or installation required by the user.

All setup needs to be done by me. I would like to pass on a box with 16 LEDs on it (with maybe a USB or any other connection) and a HTML file and I would like to tell the user "connect the box with your computer and start playing."

Comment: Doing this in a website is going to be difficult, it's very hard to get control of hardware from a web browser (they try to avoid that because of the enormous potential for abuse).

Comment: Basically, you'll need some hardware to run a server and control the LEDs, and that server can be accessed by a client on the same network. I'm not sure there's any other way to do this.

Comment: Big question is what transport mechanism you have between the HTML file and your device. You mention USB, but do you want your user to drag and drop the file to something emulating a hard drive? Custom program? Connect via serial terminal emulation?

Comment: @winny I would like to give the HTML file (and the box with the LEDs) to the user, ask the user to connect the box to the computer (USB or wifi or bluetooth or ...) open the HTML file and start using it. I will try the wifi approach suggested in the answers.

Comment: @Hearth I will try the network approach (but unfortunately so far I did not find any wifi microcontrollers that has 16 usable IO pins, so some other trick like charlieplexing or io expander is also needed). Since I asked the question, I also found about webHID, which I also would like to investigate (or hacks like https://www.aranacorp.com/en/turn-your-arduino-into-an-hid-device/ ).

Comment: Yes, but double clicking on the HTML file on the end users computer won’t automatically transfer it to your device despite it being connected. You need a transport mechanism. Please think this though first.

Comment: You could do this all client side with a USB connection, I believe. The JavaScript WebSerial API allows websites to connect and interact with serial devices, so users could open your HTML file, get a browser prompt to select a connected device, and then it could send serial commands to e.g. an Arduino that you've flashed with a program that allows it to respond to those commands and turn the lights on and off as you want. You may run into issues with `file://` not being treated as a secure origin, but could always host your HTML page on something free like github pages.

Comment: @winny I did think it through. I do not want the html on the device. I want it on the end user computer. I want a separate program on the device that can respond to messages it gets from the html on the computer. I can write both software, all I need is a way of doing this that does not involve the user installing and setting up anything. I will try the methods others suggested.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma I will have a look at WebSerial API. Do you know any specific tutorial on how to use it with arduino? The reason I asked this question in the first place is that when I tried, all I could find are tutorials using nodejs and the Johnny Five library.

Comment: _”it gets from the html on the computer”_ Please elaborate on this exact mechanism.

Comment: I suggest using addressable LEDs so that you only need 1 IO pin and can use the common ESP8266. This will be much easier and you benefit from the thousands of people who have done similar things before.

Comment: @winny Here is an example: The webpage (that runs on a computer) has 16 buttons. When a user clicks on a button, the corresponding led on the device lights up.

Comment: That did not answer my question. How is the data transferred via USB? How will the web browser access it?

Comment: @user1850479 Yes, I saw your answer below and trying to find the information I need. My problem is finding the help I need from the thousands of projects. It will take time, but I will get there hopefully. I do not want to control a led strip, I need individual plain white leds in specific positions. I know that the wled library can handle this, I just need to figure out exactly how. As I said in the post, I am a beginner, it takes time. I did not accept your answer yet, because I am not there yet in my understanding.

Comment: At a fundamental level you're doing something simple that lots of people do, so I'm trying to guide you towards common hardware and existing solutions. If you find lots of microcontrollers that work one way, but you can't find any that work a different way, it's a good sign you are going in the wrong direction. Perhaps you don't want to use wled, but you probably do want to use the same hardware as everyone else doing this.

Comment: @winny I am not sure what else to write. The setup I want to achieve is similar to a heating system that can be controlled from a smartphone. There is the device (in this example the heater) that has a built-in firmware. There is also a smartphone in my pocket with an app that lets me remotely "tell" the heater to turn on whenever I feel like it.

Comment: @user1850479 I understand that I am trying to do similar things that others also did. From what I understand, ESP32 is the tool to use, I am trying to figure out how. I am not sure why you say I am going in the wrong direction, I am going in the direction you suggested. It takes time, I need to learn things. I cannot use a led strip, because I need the leds at individual positions. I cannot use the wled app, because I want to integrate the control in my application. I will get there hopefully.

Comment: I guess it depends how you want to connect your device to the computer, right. Do you want to use WiFi or USB? Do you want support for mobile devices? etc. Is the HTML file something that you have on a third-party web server / send directly to the users, or is it hosted by the device itself? They're all valid options in my opinion with various pros and cons (e.g. something like WebSerial needs less hardware overall and pushes a lot of the work to the web client instead, but can't easily work with phones / wirelessly), so I think it's more of a question on how you want this device to be used

Comment: Would you ever want multiple people controlling it at the same time? Or is it something that gets configured once and then runs based on that configuration? etc

Comment: That’s my point, you don’t know but expect it to happen automagically. Sorry to bring bad news but it won’t. All the examples you give have made software to make this happen and you need to define how yours should work and implement it accordingly. The apps are not just HTML files stored on a file system in a device.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma No, I do not want multiple user controlling it. I do not want it to work as a website. As I wrote in my post, I want to distribute the software to be used locally on the user's computer. I chose html, because it is platform independent and what I need can nicely be written in javascript. It does not matter if the computer/tablet communicates with the device using usb or wifi (or bluetooth or any other way).

Comment: @winny I really do not see your point. I do not expect anything happen automagically and others seem to understand my question and answer in a helpful way. I said I am a beginner, I am collecting information about options. Android apps are indeed not html files, but html files can be stored on local computers and can work as apps if open with a web browser. HTML files do not have to live in the cloud, they can be run locally.

Comment: I understand you are a beginner, but solving everything except the transport mechanism will not meet your end goal. Having worked as an engineer my entire adult life, a word of advice is to start with the hardest part you know the least about first. I would suspect the easiest way is for your MCU to somehow be connected to the internet and poll for said HTML file. Again, figure out the transport mechanism first and I’m sure you can solve the rest. Best of luck!

Comment: You want people to control *their own* LEDs locally on their computers? Or control *your* LEDs on their computers through the Internet?

Answer (score 7):

This is almost exactly what the wled library does:

> A fast and feature-rich implementation of an ESP8266/ESP32 webserver to control NeoPixel (WS2812B, WS2811, SK6812) LEDs or also SPI based chipsets like the WS2801 and APA102!

https://kno.wled.ge/

You'd give them the box, tell them to connect it to wifi and then they could browse to the web server. USB control is also possible but I think that would be more complicated to setup with a web page.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the JavaScript [Web Serial API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Serial_API) to do this. This allows users to connect your website to a serial device they have plugged into their computer, and then allows your website to read and write serial data to that device. You can do this entirely on the client side, without any need for servers, etc.

There's a few pros and cons to this approach. On the one hand, you don't need any extra hardware and can potentially push a lot of work to the client software. Especially when considering other approaches that involve plugging the device into a computer, I think this is one of the best, because you don't need to download / install anything.

However, there are disadvantages: microcontrollers out-of-the-box can (typically) only interact with one serial device at a time, you have to distribute the client software separately from the device rather than having it host that itself, you have to encode everything that you want to transmit over a serial interface and deal with that yourself, it potentially gives more access than you might want to the device (e.g. with full serial access, they could install e.g. the IDE for the microcontroller and reflash it, etc).

---

I just threw together a really basic circuit to show how Web Serial transmission could work. I've got an Arduino Uno hooked up to a [74LS165N Shift Register](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls164.pdf?ts=1687257904716), with a simple program that listens for serial input, and shifts a `HIGH` onto the register when it receives a `1` over serial, or a `LOW` onto the register when it receives anything else. I've then just hooked the outputs directly up to some LEDs (and of course you could chain together multiple registers as needed to drive more lights if you want).

[image]

```c
#define CLOCK_PIN 12
#define DATA_PIN 13

void setup() {
  pinMode(CLOCK_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DATA_PIN, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() == 0) {
    return;
  }

  int nextByte = Serial.read();
  shiftValue(nextByte == 1);
}

void shiftValue(bool value) {
  digitalWrite(DATA_PIN, value);
  digitalWrite(CLOCK_PIN, LOW);
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(CLOCK_PIN, HIGH);
}
```

---

From JavaScript, you'd connect the device. This pops up a browser prompt where they can select a device that they have plugged in, and then opens a connection to it (if they didn't e.g. reject the prompt):

```
async function connect(): Promise<SerialPort | undefined> {
  try {
    const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
    await port.open({ baudRate: 9600 });

    return port;
  } catch {
    alert("Error connecting to serial device");
  }
}
```

Then, when you want to set the LEDs, you'd send out the bytes over the serial interface:

```
async function writeToSerial(
  port: SerialPort,
  data: Uint8Array
): Promise<void> {
  if (!port.writable) throw new Error("Not writable");

  const writer = port.writable.getWriter();
  await writer.write(data);
  writer.releaseLock();
}

function boolArrayToUint8Array(boolArray: boolean[]): Uint8Array {
  const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(boolArray.length);
  const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  uint8Array.set(boolArray.map((bool) => (bool ? 1 : 0)));
  return uint8Array;
}

async function sendUpdatedState(port: SerialPort, state: boolean[]): Promise<void> {
  await writeToSerial(port, boolArrayToUint8Array(state));
}
```

Which could be called like so:

```
sendUpdatedState(
 [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false]
)
```

to get, for example, an alternating pattern of lights to display.

And, of course, you could also read data from the JavaScript end too, as the serial interface provides full dual communication.

---

Here's a short GIF of this in action:

[image]

---

There's a bit that could be improved here, e.g. rather than sending one byte per LED, you could roll together the values when sending over-the-wire to send e.g. the state of 8 LEDs in just one byte (and in fact, I think you'd want to do this, as the lag from the serial connection does appear *briefly* visible when toggling things as you see the other lights flicker momentarily as the values get shifted on). However, for the purposes of the demo, I wanted to keep things as simple as possible, because the important bit is really the transport mechanism itself, not the implementation details of what is being transported and what the device is doing with the data it receives.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the functionality I need. I am still comparing the different approaches suggested in the answers, this is why I am not yet accepting this as an answer, but certainly this detailed explanation helps me understand how the web serial api works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an Arduino + WiFi shield/Ethernet shield. But now the most popular and cost-effective way is to use an ESP8266. ESP8266 16 GPIO pins. Among those, you can use 11. I can see that you need 16 GPIO pins for 16 LEDs. If you use an I/O expander for ESP8266, that may solve the problem.

Comment: ESP32 has more GPIO pins than ESP8266, so it doesn't need an I/O expander. And ESP32 doesn't cost too much more than ESP8266. ESP8266 is almost deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Any embedded controller that has an ethernet interface (OK there are other hardware interfaces to a network but they are archaic) and a working HTTP server implementation.

There is an open source library called [lwIP](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/) (Light Weight Internet Protocol) which can run either with an RTOS or in bare metal mode and this could certainly be used as a start point if your chosen microcontroller vendor doesn't have a working example.